# How set layout for Dialog?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-dialog

I tried to use

```
dialog.setLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I set the layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
 dialog.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```